# Unresolved reference: findViewById on SnackBar

Tags: android, kotlin

Am trying to add a SnackBar that is called when Delete is clicked however I am getting the error 'Unresolved reference: findViewById' when I add the Scackbar to the Delete Menu

```
        holder.menu.setOnClickListener {
            val popup = PopupMenu(activity,holder.menu)
            popup.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_child)
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener {

                when(it.itemId){
                    R.id.menu_edit->{
                        activity.updateToDo(list[p1])
                    }
                    R.id.menu_delete->{
                        activity.dbHandler.deleteToDo(list[p1].id)
                        activity.refreshList()
                        val mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(
                            findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout),
                            R.string.task_deleted, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                        mySnackbar.setAction(R.string.undo_string, MyUndoListener())
                        mySnackbar.show()
                    }

                }

                true
            }
            popup.show()
        }
```

Comment: invalidate caches/restart

Comment: You can just pass `holder.menu` there. `Snackbar` will find your `CoordinatorLayout` itself (assuming that your `RecyclerView` is somewhere inside of that `CoordinatorLayout`, that is).

Comment: @Mike M. Yes my RecylerView is inside my CoordinatorLayout. Could you post some code just for clarity?

Comment: @MMG that didn't work.

Comment: Just replace `findViewById(R.id.myCoordinatorLayout)` with `holder.menu`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to show snackbar

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content),  R.string.task_deleted, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
 snackbar .setAction(R.string.undo_string, MyUndoListener())
            snackbar.show()
```